# "would have thought" and "would think"

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

In Longman dictionary, it says that:

> "you would have thought (that) "(also you would think (that)) used to say that you expect something to be true, although it is not

Here are my examples, I don't know if I can use "would have thought" and "would think"  interchangeably for a past action:

Example 1:

> A:Tom failed the exam.
>
> B: (1) Really? I **would have thought** that he passed the examination.'
>
> B: (2) Really? I **would think** that he passed the examination.

Example 2:

> John: I gave the waiter a $50 dollar tip and he gave me a dirty look. Maybe I should have given him more?
>
> Bill:(1) No, $50 is enough, I **would have thought**.
>
> Bill:(2) No, $50 is enough, I **would think.**

Comment: For (1), "I would have thought [that] he **would have** passed the exam." (You can't say 'he passed' if he didn't pass.)

Comment: B: (1) Really? I (would have thought)/(would think) that he would never pass the examination.'. Here both (would have thought)/(would think) are correct to use. Right?

Comment: I don't find that version idiomatic. If he **did** pass unexpectedly, you might say "I would never have thought that he would/could pass that exam."

Comment: @Kate Bunting I'm glad to greet you! In your example with the negation you do not use "would" with perfect infinitive whereas you do it in the first sentence. Why is it so? And what if I said: "I would never have thought that he would have passed that exam." ?

Comment: "I would have thought he would have passed" - you expected to hear that he _had passed_ until you were told otherwise. "I would never have thought that he would pass" - Before the exam, you never said to yourself "He will pass".

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you! There is one other question on this site that doesn't add up to me: "I would have thought he made exceptions in these cases, but apparantly he doesn't". What does the Past Indefinite "made" have to do with the Present Indefinite "doesn't"? Every grammar occurence must obey some rule. Is there any rule to appliy here (that vindicates using "made")?

Comment: @Eugene - "I would have thought...", expressing surprise that something isn't as you expected, is usually followed by the past tense even when the situation is ongoing.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you! Notwithstanding my never having come across this fact (about the past tense) I'll make it the rule for me (I hope the preposition "for" is the right choice here).

Answer (score 1):

*I would have thought* is just a slightly more "hedged, hesitant" alternative to *I would think*.

Both of which are ways for a speaker to "distance" himself from what he's saying (usually for the sake of politeness / deference / formality). As it happens, in both of OP's examples the speaker is *disagreeing* with something someone else said, but the usage under consideration here is just as suitable when *agreeing* with someone...

> A: "I hope my £50 tip was enough. What do you think?"
> B: "For sure. £50 is *plenty*, I would think"

The speaker's intended meaning (which he's diffident about *explicitly* saying) is simply ***I think** [whatever I just said]*.

---

As commented by @Kate above, OP's first example doesn't really make sense, because it's a "mash-up" of two contradictory assertions - (1) *I expected that he would pass, but apparently I was wrong - he **didn't** pass*, and (2) *You are wrong - he **did** pass*.

Comment: B: (1) Really? I (would have thought)/(would think) that he would never pass the examination.'. Here both (would have thought)/(would think) are correct to use. Right?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by that. But note that B: *Really? I **would think** that he **would never pass** the examination* doesn't make sense if speaker has just been told that he ***did*** pass (unless speaker is simply dismissing that information *because he doesn't believe it*). If B says *Really? I **would have thought** that he would never pass the examination*, that's fine (he's expressing surprise, because something has happened that he didn't expect).

Comment: ...also note that introducing auxiliary ***would*** along with ***to think*** here is semantically / logically irrelevant, as pointed out in the second paragraph of my answer. So the two alternatives in my immediately preceding comment are precisely equivalent to *Really? I **think** that...* and *Really? I **thought** that...*  Hence A: *The Moon is made of green cheese.* B: *Really? I **thought** the Moon was made of rock, same as the Earth [but now you've told me different, I realise I was mistaken]*

Comment: I know that Tom doesn't have ability to pass the test, so that I still don't believe that Tome already passed the test, so that I will use : (1) I would have thought that Tom WOULDN'T PASS the test. or (2) I would have thought that Tom WOULDN'T HAVE PASSED the test. What is the difference between (1) and (2)? If I accept the truth that Tome already passed the test, I will use (3) I thought that Tom wouldn't pass the test. Right?

Comment: Check out @Kate's final comment again: *I would never have thought that he would/could pass that exam* (it's more natural to negate the *thought*, not the *passing*). Don't repeat complex verb forms as per (2) in your above comment - it's clumsy. But to be honest, I'm not sure you're gaining any benefit from this exchange. I suggest you avoid trying to use unnecessary conditionals in such contexts. *I **didn't** think he would pass* means the same as all the alternatives saying what you would or wouldn't have thought, so you should just stick to that form.

Comment: Yes, I know that "I didn't think" is more popular, but sometimes I still hear people saying " I would never thought". So I wonder what the difference between them

Comment: The conditional might *very slightly* imply *I didn't actually think / care about it enough to have formed an opinion, but **if I had thought about it**, I would have concluded that...* But that implication wouldn't necessarily be intended and/or understood - and even if it *were*, the actual positive or negative *significance* would be context-specific.

Comment: Sorry that I don’t get what you mean here “ But that implication WOULDN'T necessarily be intended and/or understood ”=> “would” here expresses a hypothesis or expresses uncertainty?

Comment: In principle, it expresses a hypothesis / counterfactual (referring to some hypothetical unreal alternative reality where I ***did*** think about this matter, whereas ***in the real universe I didn't think about it***). But as I said, I don't think this is getting you anywhere. Or I wouldn't have thought it would get you anywhere, if you want to go round the houses.

Comment: Your sentence (1) Or I wouldn't have thought it would get you anywhere. And this sentence (2)  Or I wouldn't think it would get you anywhere. What is the difference  between “wouldn’t have thought “ and “wouldn’t think”

Comment: Isn't that obvious? ***I think*** is immediate, here and now. ***I would think*** is somewhat "removed" from current reality - so it might be used to express hesitancy, deference, uncertainty, etc, depending on the exact context. Thus ***I would have thought*** is even *further* removed from current reality, which in principle means it's more "emphatically hesitant" than ***I would think***. You can figure out for yourself what if anything that might "mean" in any given context.

Comment: If so, when my friend state a fact, then I will reply*** (1) I think that you are wrong.*** (2) I would think that you are wrong ***(3) I would have thought you are wrong. 
Three sentences are good to use, the difference is that (1) sounds direct, (2) sounds more polite, and (3) sound the most polite. Right?

Comment: For the third or fourth time, I don't think this is getting you anywhere. #3 there *might* come across as the "most polite". Or it might come across as the most patronizing / insulting, depending on the exact context. You simply cannot expect to learn subtle aspects of usage like this by reading "rules" and/or asking native speakers what they think. At this level, you can only really learn by reading and/or listening to what native speakers write and/or say.

Comment: I just want to know that is it possible to use these terms. For example: My friend: The capital of the US is New York. Can I response like this : (I think)/ (I would think)/(I would have thought) that you are wrong. I can use either of them. Right?